# Compile-time decision of call parameters based on function prototype

Tags: c, gcc

Often times while working with 3rd party libraries, I find myself needing to write glue "code" to handle prototypes of functions that have changed across versions.

Taking the Linux kernel, for example: here's a common scenario - let's say we have function `int my_function(int param)` and at some point we need to add an optional `void *data`. Instead of breaking the API, the new parameter will be added this way:

```
int __my_function(int param, void *data);

static inline my_function(int param) {
    return __my_function(param, NULL);
}
```

This is nice: it hides the new parameter and API breakage from those who don't need it. Existing code can continue using `my_function` with the old prototype.

However, this is not always the case (neither in Linux nor in other libraries) and I end up with such pieces, to handle all possible versions I encounter:

```
#if LIBRARY_VERSION > 5
my_function(1, 2, 3);
#elif LIBRARY_VERSION > 4
my_function(1, 2);
#else
my_function(1);
#endif
```

So I was thinking, for simple prototype changes (reordering of parameters, addition / removal of "default" parameters, etc) it'd be nice to have the compiler do it automatically.

I want this done automatically (without needing to specify exact versions) because sometimes it's excessive work to pinpoint the exact library/kernel version in which the change was introduced. So if I don't care of the new parameter and I can just use e.g `0`, I want the compiler to use `0` whenever it needs to.

The farthest I've got is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if 1
int f(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
#else
int f(int a) {
    return a + 5;
}
#endif

int main(void) {
    int ret = 0;
    int (*p)() = (int(*)())f;
    if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(f), int(int, int)))
        ret = p(3, 4);
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(f), int(int)))
        ret = p(1);
    else
        printf("no matching call\n");
    printf("ret: %d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

This works - GCC selects the appropriate call in compile type, but it has 2 problems:

1. By calling via a "typeless" function pointer, we lose type checking. So `p("a", "b")` is legit and gives garbage results.
2. It seems like standard type promotion doesn't happen (again, probably since we make the call via a typeless pointer)

(And there might be other problems I'm missing here, but these are the most crucial points I believe)

I believe it can be taken ahead with some macros magic: if call parameters are separated, a macro can generate code that finds the appropriate prototype, then tests all given arguments for type compatibility one-by-one. But I think it'll be much more complex to use so I'm seeking a simpler solution.

Any ideas how to get this working with proper type checking + promotions? I assume it can't be done without using compiler extensions, so my question focuses on modern GCCs, targeting Linux.

**EDIT:** After macroifying it + adding Acorn's idea for the cast, I'm left with this:

```
#define START_COMPAT_CALL(f, ret_type, params, args, ret_value) if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(f), ret_type params)) (ret_value) = ( ( ret_type(*) params ) (f) ) args
#define ELSE_COMPAT_CALL(f, ret_type, params, args, ret_value) else START_COMPAT_CALL(f, ret_type, params, args, ret_value)
#define END_COMPAT_CALL() else printf("no matching call!\n")

int main(void) {
    int ret = 0;

    START_COMPAT_CALL(f, int, (int, int), (999, 9999), ret);
    ELSE_COMPAT_CALL(f, int, (int), (1), ret);
    ELSE_COMPAT_CALL(f, int, (char, char), (5, 9999), ret);
    ELSE_COMPAT_CALL(f, int, (float, int), (3, 5), ret);
    ELSE_COMPAT_CALL(f, int, (float, char), (3, 5), ret);
    END_COMPAT_CALL();
    printf("ret: %d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

This works regarding the 2 points I've noted - it gives type checking warnings and it performs promotion correctly. *But* it also emits warnings for all "unselected" call sites: `warning: function called through a non-compatible type`. I tried wrapping the call with `__builtin_choose_expr` but I no luck :/

Comment: Why would you want to do this at run-time instead of at compile-time? The run-time approach will be considerably slower. The compile-time method is indistinguishable from regular method calls.

Comment: Secondly, why not write wrapper macros that do whatever they need to in order to get the arguments correct? This would be even easier to use, as all the `#ifdef` junk is in a header file not in your calling code.

Comment: @tadman the example code is merely... an example :) Obviously once I'm good with it, I'll make it into some convenient macro.
And what do you mean by "runtime"? All those `if`s are resolved in compile-time.
I'm adding another clarification regarding what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: You're hoping they get optimized out, but that may not be the case. I'm not sure I'd trust that to happen. Compilers optimize things they know will work out, but if there's any ambiguity or potential for mistakes they won't.

Comment: Specifically continuing my example, `__builtin_types_compatible_p` is resolved completely in compile-time (AFAIK), so we can trust other branches to be optimized out. If other "selectors" are used then it might not be the case, right.

Comment: Have you looked at builtin_choose_expr? Not 100% sure but it seems to handle the problem

Comment: Yes, I tried using `__builtin_choose_expr`. Problem is, it appears to be type-checking the function of untaken branches as well (while it shouldn't, I think):
`__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(f), int(int, int)) f(5, 3), __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(f), int(int)), f(19), void)0));`

This gives an error `too few arguments to function` when `f` is defined with 2 parameters. But it shouldn't type-check that branch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in standard C using `_Generic`:

```
//  Define sample functions.
int foo(int a, int b)        { return a+b;   }
int bar(int a, int b, int c) { return a+b+c; }

//  Define names for the old and new types.
typedef int (*Type0)(int, int);
typedef int (*Type1)(int, int, int );

/*  Given an identifier (f) for a function and the arguments (a and b) we
    want to pass to it, the MyFunctio macro below uses _Generic to test which
    type the function is and call it with appropriate arguments.

    However, the unchosen items in the _Generic would contain function calls
    with mismatched arguments.  Even though these are never evaluated, they
    violate translation-time contraints for function calls.  One solution would
    be to cast the function (automatically converted to a function pointer) to
    the type being used in the call expression.  However, GCC sees through this
    and complains the function is called through a non-compatible type, even
    though it never actually is.  To solve this, the Sanitize macro is used.

    The Sanitize macro is given a function type and a function.  It uses a
    _Generic to select either the function (when it matches the type) or a null
    pointer of the type (when the function does not match the type).  (And GCC,
    although unhappy with a call to a function with wrong parameters, is happy
    with a call to a null pointer.)
*/
#define Sanitize(Type, f)   \
    _Generic((f), Type: (f), default: (Type) 0)
#define MyFunction(f, a, b)                                      \
    _Generic(f,                                                  \
        Type0:  Sanitize(Type0, (f)) ((a), (b)),   \
        Type1:  Sanitize(Type1, (f)) ((a), (b), 0) \
    )


#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", MyFunction(foo, 3, 4));
    printf("%d\n", MyFunction(bar, 3, 4));
}
```

The above use a parameterized function name (`f`) to allow us to demonstrate this with both functions (`foo` and `bar`) defined. For the situation in the question, there is only one function definition and with only one name, so we can simplify the macro. We can also use the function name for the macro name. (It is not recursively substituted during preprocessing both because C does not recursively substitute macros and because the name does not appear in the replacement text with a left parenthesis following it.) This would look like:

```
#define Sanitize(Type, f)   \
    _Generic((f), Type: (f), default: (Type) 0)
#define foo(a, b)                                  \
    _Generic(foo,                                  \
        Type0:  Sanitize(Type0, foo) ((a), (b)),   \
        Type1:  Sanitize(Type1, foo) ((a), (b), 0) \
    )
…
    printf("%d\n", foo(3, 4));
```

(The definition of `Sanitize` used here was provided by [Artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754656/artyer) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63420570/2770331).)

Comment: Cool! I wasn't aware of this syntax. I defined `typedef int (*f_v1)(int, int); typedef int (*f_v2)(int);` and while `f` is `int f(int a, int b)` I still get `warning: function called through a non-compatible type` on `f_v2: ((f_v2)f)(3)`.

Comment: @Jong: Looks like GCC is tracking the type through the cast, but Clang is not.

Comment: @Jong: I updated with a workaround that satisfies GCC and Clang. I believe this is strictly conforming C code, but there is no guarantee future versions of GCC and Clang will not complain.

Comment: Very nice. This works for me on GCC 5 and GCC 7 :) Do you know perhaps why the compound literal makes any difference for GCC? The compound literal prevents GCC from tracking across it? Also, I'd expect that GCC's behavior here will match Clang's - no type checking on the untaken branch. But in `_Generic` as well as `__builtin_choose_expr`, it does type-check. Is it a bug?

Comment: @Jong: The compound literal works simply because GCC does not track types across it. I do not expect there is any reason for that other than it has not been implemented yet—it could track the types. I have another solution in mind that uses nested `_Generic` operators to ensure no mismatched function call is present in the source, so arguably a compiler must accept it, but it would be a mess. I think the type checking in this case could be considered a bug since the code will never evaluate a call with undefined behavior; the mismatched type occurs only in unevaluated code.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Jong: I updated with a version (in a supplement at the end) I think a compiler cannot complain about. The issues raised here might be good to ask with a language-lawyer tag.

Comment: @TS: I am planning on moving the supplement to the main answer and removing the earlier code. When I get more time.

Answer (score 1):

The standard and best approach is writing a wrapper with the `#ifdef`s testing inside it:

```
int my_function(int param)
{
#if LIBRARY_VERSION > 5
    return lib_my_function(param, 2, 3);
#elif LIBRARY_VERSION > 4
    return lib_my_function(param, 2);
#else
    return lib_my_function(param);
#endif
}
```

Which then you call like:

```
my_function(1);
```

No need for macro magic, type checking works as usual, future API changes in the library are localized, IDEs and coworkers do not get confused, etc.

---

Side-note: if you really want to go with your proposed solution, then you can keep the type-checking by creating the proper pointer for each alternative:

```
if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(f), int(int, int)))
    ret = ((int(*)(int, int)) f)(3, 4);
else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(f), int(int)))
    ret = ((int(*)(int)) f)(1);
else
    printf("no matching call\n");
```

But really, there is no advantage for that since you have anyway `#ifdef` for defining the proper `f`. At that point, you might as well define it as shown above and avoid all that, plus no need for GNU extensions.

Comment: That's indeed the standard solution, but I'm trying to avoid it: I'm sorry, I forgot to add my main motive for this in the question (added 4 mins ago): I want this trick because it allows to use the "right" version without knowing exactly in which version a change is introduced. When compiling for the Linux kernel, for example, it's easy to find when did the change get mainlined, but distros may backport it and you then need to check for the Linux version + CentOS version + Ubuntu version + ...

Comment: Your side-note might work, I'm trying to "macroify" it now.

Comment: @Jong I am not sure what you mean by "compiling for the Linux kernel". The kernel guarantees ABI stability for the syscall boundary, so userspace should never need to change anything. Other common APIs like C and POSIX are also extremely conservative. Perhaps you are working on a proprietary kernel module? In such a case... yeah, it is a pain, but that is usually solved with a build script that figures out what the available APIs are. Trying to guess by function signatures is fragile and cannot cover all cases (what if the types did not change, yet the semantics did?).

Comment: I'm talking about kernel development in general, not aimed at proprietary, it's just about the need to support many kernel versions with one source. This method doesn't help with "semantics change, prototype stays", yes, but I was seeking help with the "semantics stay, prototype changes to reorder parameters / add some optional parameters", in which case it helps very much :)

Comment: @Jong That is why open source kernel development should be upstreamed: you avoid these problems. I would be really careful with your proposal, because it can break silently. Even stable kernel versions could change the semantics in a way that breaks your code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this:

```
int f (int a) {         // OLD API
    return a + 5;
}

int f (int a, int b) {  // NEW API
    return a + b;
}
```

Then you can write a macro that checks the number of parameters passed, then call the actual function or a wrapper based on that:

```
static int f_wrapper (int a)
{
  return f(a, 0);
}

#define p(...) _Generic( &(int[]){__VA_ARGS__},       \
                 int(*)[2]: f,                        \
                 int(*)[1]: f_wrapper) (__VA_ARGS__)
```

Here the `(int[]){ __VA_ARGS__}` creates a dummy `int[]` array in the form of a compound literal. It will get 1 or 2 items based on the caller code. Type safety during storage to this dummy array will be the same as during function call - parameters/expressions convertible to `int` are accepted, others will yield compiler errors.

The `&(int[]) ...` takes the address of this dummy compound literal to generate an array pointer type - we can't have array types inside `_Generic` (because an array passed to _Generic will decay to a pointer) but we can have distinct array pointer types. So depending on if we ended up with an `int[2]` or `int[1]`, the corresponding `_Generic` clause will get picked (or if no matches, compiler error).

The main advantage of this code is that no modifications are needed in the caller code, they can use `p()` with either 1 or 2 parameters.

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* 
int f (int a) {         // OLD API
    return a + 5;
}
*/

int f (int a, int b) {  // NEW API
    return a + b;
}


static int f_wrapper (int a)
{
  return f(a, 0);
}

#define p(...) _Generic( &(int[]){__VA_ARGS__},       \
                 int(*)[2]: f,                        \
                 int(*)[1]: f_wrapper) (__VA_ARGS__)

int main (void) 
{
  int ret = 0;
  ret = p(3, 4);
  printf("ret: %d\n", ret);
  ret = p(1);
  printf("ret: %d\n", ret);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ret: 7
ret: 1
```

gcc x86 -O3

```
f:
        lea     eax, [rdi+rsi]
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "ret: %d\n"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     esi, 7
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        mov     esi, 1
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

As we can see from the disassembly, everything was handled in compile time and inlined - no temporary arrays etc are actually created.