# Applying C requirements to unselected _Generic cases

Tags: c, language-lawyer

(Note this is a language-lawyer question.)

### Deprecated Question

**Update:** I botched Question 0. When I wrote this, I was looking at the parameter-argument type rules in C 2018 6.5.2.2 6, which are not in a Constraints section and so may be neglected by a compiler. I overlooked 6.5.2.2 2, which is in a Constraints section, so a compiler is required to diagnose mismatched types. I would not have asked Question 0 if I had noticed this.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63403418/compile-time-decision-of-call-parameters-based-on-function-prototype), we desire code such as:

```
int AddVersion0(int a, int b       ) { return a+b;   }
int AddVersion1(int a, int b, int c) { return a+b+c; }

typedef int (*TypeVersion0)(int, int);
typedef int (*TypeVersion1)(int, int, int);

#define Foo(f, a, b)    _Generic((f),  \
        TypeVersion0: (f)((a), (b)),   \
        TypeVersion1: (f)((a), (b), 0) \
    )

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", Foo(AddVersion0, 3, 4));
    printf("%d\n", Foo(AddVersion1, 3, 4));
}
```

(`Foo` has been parameterized with a function `f` to facilitate demonstration and analysis.
In the original context, this is not needed.)

With default switches, optionally adding `-std=c18`, both GCC 10.2 and
Apple Clang 11.0 [reject this code](https://godbolt.org/z/cWEcz3) complaining as an error, not a warning, there are too many arguments to one function call (`AddVersion0` in the second case of the first use of `Foo`) and too few to another (`AddVersion1` in the first case of the second).

**Question 0:**  Is this code strictly conforming to the C standard, so GCC and Clang are wrong to reject it? Not only are the mismatched cases never evaluated in an executing program, they effectively do not exist after the `_Generic` is processed because `_Generic` is defined to produce a “result expression,” not a “result value,” in C 2018 6.5.1.1 3. GCC and Clang are applying run-time constraints on a function call to a function call that does not become part of the program. 6.5.1.1 3 includes:

> If a generic selection has a generic association with a type name that is compatible with the type of the controlling expression, then the result expression of the generic selection is the expression in that generic association.

### Question 1

Next, consider this workaround:

```
int AddVersion0(int a, int b       ) { return a+b;   }
int AddVersion1(int a, int b, int c) { return a+b+c; }

typedef int (*TypeVersion0)(int, int);
typedef int (*TypeVersion1)(int, int, int);

int NeverCalled();
#define Sanitize(Type, f)   _Generic((f), Type: (f), default: NeverCalled)
#define Foo(f, a, b)    _Generic((f),  \
        TypeVersion0: Sanitize(TypeVersion0, (f))((a), (b)),   \
        TypeVersion1: Sanitize(TypeVersion1, (f))((a), (b), 0) \
    )

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", Foo(AddVersion0, 3, 4));
    printf("%d\n", Foo(AddVersion1, 3, 4));
}
```

Neither GCC 10.2 nor Apple Clang 11.0 complain about this.

**Question 1:** Could a compiler have grounds to complain about this? As `NeverCalled` is not declared with a prototype, C 2018 6.5.2.2 6 does not say any call has undefined behavior unless the function is **defined** with a type that does not include a prototype and the argument types do not match the parameter types. But the function is not defined at all, so that condition is
not triggered.

(I ask whether the compiler has grounds for complaint because of course a compiler is permitted to complain about anything, as a warning that does not prevent compiling the program, but the question is whether a compiler could deduce that some aspect of this code violates some aspect of the C standard.)

Comment: This looks like a quality-of-implementation issue. The standard states that non-selected expressions are not evaluated. It doesn't say when or how the generic selection should be parsed. Human intuition suggests that phase 4 (§5.1.1.2p4) would be the logical choice. However, none of the type information that generic selection requires in known in phase 4. So it appears that gcc and clang defer generic selection until phase 7.

Comment: @user3386109: "Not evaluated" doesn't relax constraints. For example, `1 || AddVersion0(0,0,0)` is still a constraint violation.

Comment: [GCC folks told that rejecting code because of constraint violations in unselected cases is not a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64509)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Question 0**: Is this code strictly conforming to the C standard, so GCC and Clang are wrong to reject it?

No.

> Not only are the mismatched
> cases never evaluated in an executing program,

Whether unselected expressions are evaluated is not relevant.  The expressions still need to be *assignment-expressions* according to the grammar presented in the standard.  Unwinding that production to find how it applies to the code at issue, we find that it exercises one of the options for a *postfix-expression* (section 6.5.2). Section 6.5.2.2 applies, and among the language constraints it it specifies is that

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> includes a prototype, the number of arguments shall agree with the
> number of parameters. Each argument shall have a type such that
> itsvalue may be assigned to an object with the unqualified version of
> the type of its corresponding parameter.

I do not take the wording "the expression that denotes the called function" to mean that the constraint applies only in the event that the function call is evaluated, but rather as a reasonable choice among the various awkward ways of referring to the expression corresponding to the *postfix-expression* production in the formal grammar.

> they effectively do not
> exist after the `_Generic` is processed because `_Generic` is defined to
> produce a “result expression,” not a “result value,” in C 2018 6.5.1.1

No, a generic selection is not defined to produce an expression.  The term "result expression" is defined in section 6.5.1.1 as the one that is selected based on the type of the controlling expression, but its significance is in determining the result of evaluating the generic selection, per paragraph 6.5.1.1/4:

> The type and value of a generic selection are identical to those of
> its result expression.  It is an lvalue, a function designator, or a
> void expression if its result expression is, respectively, an lvalue,
> a function designator, or a void expression.

The result expression is not itself, as an expression, the result of evaluating the generic selection.

Although the result expression for any given generic selection expression is known statically, that does not make the expressions with other associations, which will never be evaluated, fail to be part of the program.  This is a consequence of generic selection being part of the language proper, as opposed to being a preprocessing feature.

> 3. GCC and Clang are applying run-time constraints on a function call to a function call that does not become part of the program.

I do not accept that expressions present in the source after preprocessing fail to be part of the program on account of being dead code.  I am not aware of any significant sentiment that other forms of dead code fail to be "part of the program" in the sense that they are excused from conforming to language constraints.

On the other hand, although compilers are obligated to diagnose constraint violations, they are not obligated to reject programs containing them.  I would consider it an eminently reasonable behavior in this case to emit warnings about the argument count mismatch for the unselected expressions, but accept the code nevertheless, since the mismatches are of no particular account.

> **Question 1**: Could a compiler have grounds to complain about this? As `NeverCalled` is not declared with a prototype, C 2018 6.5.2.2 6 does
> not say any call has undefined behavior unless the function is **defined**
> with a type that does not include a prototype and the argument types
> do not match the parameter types. But the function is not defined at
> all, so that condition is not triggered.

I agree that since `NeverCalled` is not defined or even declared with a prototype, it provides no basis for even a potential violation of the constraints in section 6.5.2.2/2.  Since the inner generic selection evaluates to a function designator (which is allowed), not a function call, and since that does not end up producing a call to `NeverCalled()`, I also see no *bona fide* basis for even a warning about calling a function without an in-scope prototype.  I could imagine a compiler issuing such a warning anyway if its expression analysis were not up to snuff, but I would consider such a warning spurious.

**Update:**

However, having reviewed @Artyer's answer, I am convinced that the second example exhibits undefined behavior, which constitutes at least a reasonable pretext for a compiler that recognizes it to complain.  The relevant provision is from paragraph 6.9/5:

> If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an
> expression (other than as part of the operand of
> a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator whose result is an integer constant),
> somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external
> definition for the identifier

That the function designator represented by the external identifier `NeverCalled` is not used to form a function call expression is not among the exclusions from that requirement, nor is there any other basis for an exclusion.  Therefore, if there is no external definition of that function in the program then the program violates a "shall" requirement outside a constraint, and so has undefined behavior.  That would constitute grounds for a compiler to complain, though I certainly hope none would reject the program on those grounds.

Of course, you could just provide a definition of `NeverCalled()` to work around that.  The definition does not need to be in scope anywhere that the generic selection appears, and since the function is never called, it is in particular never called with the wrong number or type of arguments.

Answer (score 6):

Your first code snippet does not form a valid standards-conforming translation unit.

When `Foo(AddVersion0, 3, 4)` is expanded, it basically becomes:

```c
_Generic((AddVersion0),
    TypeVersion0: (AddVersion0)((3), (4)),
    TypeVersion1: (AddVersion0)((3), (4), 0)
)
```

which for the purposes of this question is equivalent to:

```c
_Generic(1,
    int: AddVersion0(3, 4),
    void*: AddVersion0(3, 4, 0)
)
```

The syntax of generic selection is defined (in section 6.5.1.1) as:

> Syntax
> *generic-selection*:
>
> > `_Generic` `(` *assignment-expression*, *generic-assoc-list* `)`
>
> *generic-assoc-list*:
>
> > *generic-association*
> > *generic-assoc-list* `,` *generic-association*
>
> *generic-association*:
>
> > *type-name* `:` *assignment-expression*
> > **`default`** `:` *assignment-expression*

Now the second invalid case's assignment-expression is parsed as a function call postfix-expression (§6.5.2) (where postfix-expressions are also assignment-expressions):

> *postfix-expression*:
>
> > [...]
> > *postfix-expression* `(` *argument-expression-list*<sub>opt</sub> `)`

The section on function calls later on (§6.5.2.2p2) says in the constraints paragraphs:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that includes a prototype, the number of arguments shall agree with the number of parameters.

(Where the "called function" is `AddVersion0` implicitly converted to a function pointer with a prototype with 2 parameters, and the number of arguments is 3)

Thus the expression in the second branch violates a "shall" requirement since a different number of arguments is supplied.

The standard only has this to say about the other generic associations (Excerpt from §6.5.1.1p3):

> None of the expressions from any other generic association of the generic selection is evaluated.

It does not say that they are allowed to be invalid expressions, so no exception is made.

---

As for workarounds, you could cast to the correct function type, which wouldn't be UB since the wrong type function call will never be evaluated:

```c
#define Foo(f, a, b)    _Generic((f),  \
        TypeVersion0: ((TypeVersion0)(f))((a), (b)),   \
        TypeVersion1: ((TypeVersion1)(f))((a), (b), 0) \
    )
```

But this still brings up warnings in gcc (but not clang) for "function called through a non-compatible type". Changing to `((int(*)())(f)` seems to be a pessimisation, changing the calling convention if the function is in a different translation unit.

You could also use your `Sanitize` with a null function pointer:

```c
#define Sanitize(Type, f)   _Generic((f), Type: (f), default: (Type) 0)
```

Your workaround works for the same reason that this works (i.e., links and executes properly):

```c
int NeverCalled();
int main() {
    if (0) NeverCalled();
}
```

It is UB, since the generic selection still "uses" `NeverCalled`. In annex J, Undefined behavior, this is written:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> - [...]
> - An identifier with external linkage is used, but in the program there does not exist exactly one external definition of the identifier

Comment: _Your first code snippet is undefined behaviour... the expression in the second branch violates a "shall" requirement_ [If a ''shall'' or ''shall not'' requirement **that appears outside of a constraint** or runtime- constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p2). The "shall" requirement is **inside** the **Constraints** subsection.

Comment: So it is a diagnosable rule violation ([A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint ...](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.3p1)) (Well, OK, calling a function with number of arguments ≠ number of parameters is UB, but you don't cite that non-Constraints paragraph).

Comment: Annex J is non-normative, and sometimes uses language that loses some of the nuance of the normative provisions that it summarizes.  It would be well, then, to support your assertion that the second code exhibits UB by referring to the normative provisions that say so, rather than to Annex J.  In particular, that appears to be paragraph 6.9/5.