# How to make types configurable with preprocessor directives in C?

Tags: c, c99

As of now, I have something like the following code in the header file of my library (names changed for clarity):

```
#ifndef CFG_RESULT_TYPE
#define CFG_RESULT_TYPE double
#endif

#if CFG_RESULT_TYPE == float
#define result_parser strtof
#elif CFG_RESULT_TYPE == double
#define result_parser strtod
#elif CFG_RESULT_TYPE == long double
#define result_parser strtold
#else
#error "Invalid result type"
#endif

typedef RESULT_TYPE result_t
```

I thought this would work, and it seems to for `float` and `double` (then again, maybe it's actually undefined behavior), but not for `long double`. What is the correct way to implement this?

I should also add that `_Generic` is out of the question; I am stuck on the C99 standard for this project.

Comment: `#if` can only do numeric comparisons, it doesn't compare strings. Tokens that aren't macros are treated as `0`, so `#if CFG_RESULT_TYPE == float` is treated like `#if CFG_RESULT_TYPE == 0`

Comment: [Can be done with the _Generic keyword.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68309201/weird-gcc-warning-with-generic/68309379#68309379)

Comment: @user3386109 sorry, I should have specified that I am stuck on C99. I have edited the post to include that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define DOUBLE 1
#define FLOAT 2
#define LONG_DOUBLE 3

#ifndef CFG_RESULT_TYPE
#define CFG_RESULT_TYPE DOUBLE
#endif

#if CFG_RESULT_TYPE == FLOAT
    #define result_parser strtof
    #define RESULT_TYPE float
#elif CFG_RESULT_TYPE == DOUBLE
    #define result_parser strtod
    #define RESULT_TYPE double
#elif CFG_RESULT_TYPE == LONG_DOUBLE
    #define result_parser   strtold
    #define RESULT_TYPE long double
#else
 #error "Invalid result type"
#endif

#ifdef RESULT_TYPE
typedef RESULT_TYPE result_t;
#endif
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Although, I must admit it seems like bad practice to `#define` macros like `DOUBLE` when the header is meant to be included in other projects.

Comment: @QuaternionsRock what is wrong with `DOUBLE`?